# How to restart explorer without taskkill

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, explorer

Is there a way to restart explorer without `taskkill`?

I write a program, in it I make some changes in registry, and to apply these changes it needs to restart explorer.exe, but I don't want to use `taskkill`, is there any other way to restart `explorer.exe`?

Comment: So, you have found out how to restart other programs, but that doesn't work with Explorer? In what way does it not work?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt no it works with explorer, but I don't want to use it, taskkill close all opened windows and I don't want this happens

Comment: @mopebi  those windows ARE the explorer.exe, it's file explorer, the main shell of GUI

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yes, but I don't want to lose them, you know my program is something like an installation and  it's so bad to lose the open windows

Comment: And where do you think those open windows comes from? Computing isn't magic, you kill the process, you lose the window.

Comment: The usual etiquette major installers are taking are requesting permission to close the explorer, so the user can finish whatever they're doing then continue installation, or accept that the program isn't usable until reboot.

Comment: @Martheen my program isn't a big program, it's a college home work to simulate `Taskbar Settings > Taskbar > Turn system icon on or off` I wrote the code and if the user for example select to hide  the clock icon I change `HideClock` in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` and I think there is some ways to don't need to taskkill the explorer.exe because when we do these changes in  Taskbar Settings it doesn't need any thing

Comment: @mopebi nah, MS intentionally made those changes unavailable for programs to avoid malicious\annoying behavior. Fact it is still available through unprotected branch  of registry is a weakness. You would need to restart explorer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Restart Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/about-restart-manager):

> The Restart Manager stops applications in the following order, and
>   after the applications have been updated, restarts applications that
>   have been registered for restart in the reverse order.
>
> - GUI applications
> - Console applications
> - Windows services Windows
> - explorer

Comment: thank you, does this way good for my case? _my program isn't a big program, it's a college home work to simulate Taskbar Settings > Taskbar > Turn system icon on or off I wrote the code and if the user for example select to hide the clock icon I change HideClock in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer and I think there is some ways to don't need to taskkill the explorer.exe because when we do these changes in Taskbar Settings it doesn't need any thing_

Comment: @mop - I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work, and this is the official Microsoft way. Since it's cooperating with explorer, folder view windows that were open prior to restart are reopened after restart, so the end-user experience is almost seamless. Many vendors use that for their setup that need to install shell extension for example.

Comment: thank you, I used it, it works correctly, but the problem is that when I use `RmShutdown` and then `RmRestart` the screen go black and taskbar disappears (just like when we restart explorer in task manager). I don't like this happens, I want to apply these changes like when we change them from `Taskbar Settings > Taskbar > Turn system icon on or off` is there any way?

Comment: @mopebi - If I remember correctly, the taskbar disappears and reappears yes. So it kinda flicker and that's visually not nice. However, this is still the way to go. One thing to check everything is working correctly is to verify opened views (like File Explorer views) should be reopened automatically in the state (position, size, content, etc.) they were left before shutdown

Answer (score 1):

[Sheng Jiang's blog](https://jiangsheng.net/2013/01/22/how-to-restart-windows-explorer-programmatically-using-restart-manager/) (from Microsoft) has a nice article explaining how to restart Explorer gracefully using the Restart Manager API:

```
//returns the process id and create time for the oldest explorer.exe 
RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS GetExplorerApplication()
{
    RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS  result={0};
    DWORD bytesReturned=0;
    DWORD processIdSize=4096;
    std::vector<DWORD> processIds;
    processIds.resize(1024);
    EnumProcesses(processIds.data(),processIdSize,&bytesReturned);
    while(bytesReturned==processIdSize)
    {
        processIdSize+=processIdSize;
        processIds.resize(processIdSize/4);
        EnumProcesses(processIds.data(),processIdSize,&bytesReturned);
    }    std::for_each(processIds.begin(), processIds.end(), [&result] (DWORD processId) {
         HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processId);
         if (hProcess) {
            std::wstring imageName;
            imageName.resize(4096);
            if(GetProcessImageFileName (hProcess,(LPWSTR)imageName.data(),4096)>0)
            {
                if(wcscmp(L"explorer.exe",PathFindFileName(imageName.data()))==0)
                {
                    //this is assmuing the user is not running elevated and won't see explorer processes in other sessions
                    FILETIME ftCreate, ftExit, ftKernel, ftUser;
                    if (GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreate, &ftExit,&ftKernel, &ftUser))
                    {
                        if(result.dwProcessId==0)
                        {
                            result.dwProcessId=processId;
                            result.ProcessStartTime=ftCreate;
                        }
                        else if(CompareFileTime(&result.ProcessStartTime,&ftCreate)>0)
                        {
                            result.dwProcessId=processId;
                            result.ProcessStartTime=ftCreate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
         }
    });
    return result;
}

//taskbar position calculating code omitted
    DWORD dwSession=0;
    WCHAR szSessionKey[CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY+1] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwError = RmStartSession(&dwSession, 0, szSessionKey);
    if (dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS rgApplications[1]={GetExplorerApplication()};
        dwError=RmRegisterResources(
            dwSession,0,NULL,1,rgApplications,0,NULL);
        DWORD dwReason;
        UINT nProcInfoNeeded;
        UINT nProcInfo = 10;
        RM_PROCESS_INFO rgpi[10];
        dwError = RmGetList(dwSession, &nProcInfoNeeded,
                       &nProcInfo, rgpi, &dwReason);
        if(dwReason==RmRebootReasonNone)//now free to restart explorer
        {
            RmShutdown(dwSession,RmForceShutdown,NULL);//important, if we change the registry before shutting down explorer will override our change
            //using undocumented setting structure, could break any time
            //edge setting is stored at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2!Settings
            HKEY hKey={0};
            DWORD result=0;
            result=::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\StuckRects2"),
                    0, KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE, &hKey) ;
            if (result== ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                std::vector<BYTE> data;
                data.resize(256);
                TCHAR settingValue[]= _T("Settings");
                DWORD dwKeyDataType=0;
                DWORD dwDataBufSize=data.size();
                result=::RegQueryValueEx(hKey,settingValue, NULL, &dwKeyDataType,
                    (LPBYTE) data.data(), &dwDataBufSize);
                while(ERROR_MORE_DATA==result)
                {
                    data.resize(256+data.size());
                    dwDataBufSize=data.size();
                    result=::RegQueryValueEx(hKey,settingValue, NULL, &dwKeyDataType, 
                        (LPBYTE) data.data(), &dwDataBufSize);
                }
                data.resize(dwDataBufSize);
                if(result==ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    switch ( dwKeyDataType )
                    {
                        case REG_BINARY:
                            if(data.size()==40)
                            {
                                BYTE taskbarPosition=data[12];
                                taskbarPosition=edge;
                                data[12]=taskbarPosition;
                                RECT* taskbarRect=(RECT*)&data[24];
                                CopyRect (taskbarRect,&abd.rc);
                                result=::RegSetValueEx(hKey,settingValue,0,REG_BINARY,(LPBYTE) data.data(), dwDataBufSize);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                ::RegCloseKey( hKey );
            }
            RmRestart (dwSession,0,NULL);
        }
    }
    RmEndSession(dwSession);
```

Comment: thank you, I used it, it works correctly, but the problem is that when I use `RmShutdown` and then `RmRestart` the screen go black and taskbar disappears (just like when we restart explorer in task manager). I don't like this happens, I want to apply these changes like when we change them from `Taskbar Settings > Taskbar > Turn system icon on or off` is there any way?

Comment: That's a different question- how to turn off system icon without restarting explorer. I don't know that sorry..

Comment: @mopebi: As a matter of interest, (Taskbar aside), did you try painting the current desktop wallpaper on screen after `RMShutdown?`

Answer (score 0):

It could be not necessary to restart explorer at all.

There may be some Windows message that does the trick of updating necessary stuff.
For example notification area icons are recreated on `RegiserWindowsMessage("TaskbarCreated")` and some of settings apply on `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`.

Or maybe the setting in question is accessible via API that does refresh in addition to registry write.

Consider "softer" approaches before resorting to restart.

Comment: I test `SendMessage(GetSystemTray(), WM_PAINT, 0, 0);` and `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, 0);` after my changes in registry but it had no effect...

Comment: These were just examples, there are more ways of refreshing. Most of such settings should just be changed by some APIs, so these APIs do both refresh and registry update. For shell, there are a lot of shell API functions and inyerfaces.

Comment: Using `procmon` and looking into call stack of registry change may help finding the right API. Or disclosing the setting in question.